# Как отрезать домен из строки

Tags: php

```
https://test.ru/test-url/other
http://test.ru/test-url
//test.ru/test-url
https://www.test.ru/test-url/other
http://www.test.ru/test-url
www.test.ru/test-url/other
test.ru/test-url
testru/test-url/other
```

Надо получить test-url/other

parse_url не предлагать, я его пробовал, он с половиной этих адресов не умеет работать и определять что это ссылки, тем более он сейчас используется

Comment: Регулярные выражение например.

Comment: если бы умел регулярки, я бы не спрашивал

Comment: [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: Что вы сделали для решения свой задачи? С какими проблемами столкнулись?

Comment: if(strpos($item, '/')){
       $item = parse_url($item, PHP_URL_PATH);
       $item = stristr($item, '/');
}
                
$item = str_replace(['(', ')', '/', '`', '\'', '-', '+', '=', '<', '>', '"', ' '], '', $item);
$item = trim($item);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем случае достаточно нормализовать [URI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI) и потом отрезать все до первого слыша. Ну или просто взять и отрезать все от первого слыша, убрав предварительно разделитель протокола:

```
// Сама функция
function removeDomain($url) {
    $withoutProtocolDelimiter = str_replace('//', '', $url);
    return substr($withoutProtocolDelimiter, strpos($withoutProtocolDelimiter, '/') + 1);
}

// Проверочный массив
$array = [
    "https://test.ru/test-url",
    "http://test.ru/test-url",
    "//test.ru/test-url",
    "https://www.test.ru/test-url",
    "http://www.test.ru/test-url",
    "www.test.ru/test-url",
    "test.ru/test-url",
    "testru/test-url",
    "ftp://test.ru/test-url",
    "smb://test.ru/test-url",
    "/test-url",
];

// Проверка
foreach($array as $url) {
    echo assert(removeDomain($url) === 'test-url'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Незачем использовать регулярки, там, где они не нужны. Этот код будет работать быстрее и обработает даже результаты типа `ftp://test.ru/test-url` или `smb://test.ru/test-url`. И код настолько простой, что в нем разобраться и его поддерживать может даже джуниор.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде работает, потестирую еще.

Comment: Мне кажется джуниору читая код будет совсем не очевидно что вы там пытаетесь проделать с url. Привел ниже свой вариант, мне кажется он более читаемый (ну тернарку можно вынести отдельной строкой и в классическом синтаксисе).

Comment: @Nsk не согласен, как раз тернарные операторы убивают читаемость, особенно сложенные или длинные

Comment: @Nsk а насчет джунов – если человек не может прочесть две строчки кода с элементарными 3 функциями, то это даже не джун

Comment: @korytoff, да тернарный оператор это частность, убрал я его для кого привычнее. Вопрос в прозрачности - когда видишь parse_url с  PHP_URL_PATH в строке то сразу понятно что тут делается, а вот когда идут какие то строковые вычисления надо всматриваться и анализировать + искать функции с которыми они работают. И эти "две строчки" идут еще с сотнями-тысячами строк другого кода.

Comment: @korytoff, ну и насчет тернарников впрягусь. Я бы пожалуй не взял даже джуном человека который не пишет тернарниками. А если еще он их и прочитать не может в простейших конструкциях, имхо, работать ему с языком рано.

Comment: @korytoff, но твое решение мне нравится. Если бы речь шла не про url то конечно абсолютно не нужен parse_url.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте регулярки, вот например которая подойдет вам:

```
/^(https?:)?(\/\/)?[^\/]+(.+)$/m
```

Эта регулярка вернет "без" первого слэша

```
/^(https?:)?(\/\/)?[^\/]+\/(.+)$/m
```

Как использовать:

```
$InStr = "https://test.ru/test-url"."\r\n".
         "http://test.ru/test-url";
preg_match_all('/^(https?:)?(\/\/)?[^\/]+(.+)$/m',$InStr,$mathes);
print_r($matches);

foreach($matches as $val)
echo $val[3]
```

Чуть не забыл, пример : https://regex101.com/r/kqm48P/1/

Comment: а там в $matches получается всегда на выходе со слешем /test-url
и там в примере 8 результатов. это для каждой строки отодельно?

Comment: А вам надо без?

Comment: ага. надо все отрезать что до слеша слева вместе с ним

Comment: Посмотрите вторую регулярку из ответа =) (дополнил)

Comment: то есть чтобы получить результат надо взять $mathes[3] верно? он при любом варианте урл будет результатом?

Comment: @Alex результат брать из `$mathes[$i][3]` если передавали массив строк. но там будет не всегда url, там будет текст после одинарного слэша, т.е. нет проверки что до `/` идет именно URL

Comment: а откуда $i возьмется? у меня одна строка приходит, мне надо строку и получить в итоге отрезанную.

Comment: @Alex Дополнил ответ чтобы понять откуда может взяться `$i`, если передаете на вход одну строку то ваш ответ должен быть(на память не помню точно, но вроде так) в `$matches[0][3]`

Comment: Спасибо, вроде работает, потестирую еще

Answer (score 0):

Может просто url нормализовать под parse_url?

```
$array = [
    "https://test.ru/test-url",
    "http://test.ru/test-url",
    "//test.ru/test-url",
    "https://www.test.ru/test-url",
    "http://www.test.ru/test-url",
    "www.test.ru/test-url",
    "test.ru/test-url",
    "testru/test-url",
    "ftp://test.ru/test-url",
    "smb://test.ru/test-url",
    "test.ru/test/url/html.php",
];

foreach($array as $url) {
    echo '<li>'.parse_url( strpos($url,'//')!==false ? $url : '//'.$url, PHP_URL_PATH);
}
```

Чуть проще для восприятия

```
foreach($array as $url) {
    if( strpos($url,'//') === false ) $url='//'.$url;
    echo '<li>'.parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
}
```